# Ionic 2 Mobile App Not Hiding Address bar on Deploy

Tags: android, ionic2, mobile-safari

I have built an Ionic 2 mobile app using Ionic 2 and Angular 2. I ran ionic build android and deployed it to an azure website and it functions fine. The issue is trying to make the address bar go away. When i run an android emulator and open the url via browser, the address bar is still visible.I am relatively new to mobile development, and im not sure if what i am trying to accomplish is even possible. I do notice that when the app is run from inapp browser, the address bar goes away.

Here is what i have tried:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" /> (config.xml)

(mainComponent.ts)
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

constructor(platform: Platform) {
platform.ready().then(() => {
  StatusBar.hide();
  Splashscreen.hide();

});
}
```

Answer (score -2):

With Ionic, you don't make a website that is just mobile friendly. 
Ionic wraps your website into an App that you install on your phone just like a native app

to run your app you use this Ionic command

> $ ionic run android

I suggest reading [Testing Your App](https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html) documentation.